# Quickly changing the recipients of an Item in Outlook VSTO

Tags: outlook, vsto

The Outlook add-in I am developing is required to replace the entire `Recipients` collection of a `MailItem`. The officially sanctioned solution involves doing something like the following:

```
// Clear the old recipients.
while (mailItem.Recipients.Count > 0)
{
    mailItem.Recipients.Remove(1);
}

// Insert the new recipients.
foreach (var newRecipient in newRecipients)
{
    mailItem.Recipients.Add(newRecipient);
}
```

Unfortunately this simply doesn't scale to a large number of recipients (on the order of hundreds of recipients). Each change to the `Recipients` collection appears to incur significant overhead because Outlook needs to refresh the GUI (this is visible as a rapid flickering of the to/cc/bcc fields in the compose window). My experiments show that, on my machine, going through this procedure with a few hundred recipients takes over a minute (!) to complete.

To mitigate this I came up with the following much faster solution:

```
// Clear the old recipients.
mailItem.To = null;
mailItem.CC = null;
mailItem.BCC = null;

// Insert the new recipients.
// We pretend that the CC and BCC fields are empty for now.
mailItem.To = string.Join(";", newRecipients);
```

The `To` property is writable, and the code appears to behave correctly. However, I'm worried about the following remark in the [VSTO documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.to.aspx):

> This property contains the display names only. The To property corresponds to the MAPI property PidTagDisplayTo. The Recipients collection should be used to modify this property.

I'm not sure how I should interpret this. If `To` shouldn't be directly manipulated, why is it read-write? My question to the Outlook gurus is:

**Is this safe, and simply undocumented, or am I likely to run into significant problems by indirectly manipulating the recipients in this manner?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will work just fine. What MSDN is trying to say is that **reading** the To property might only give you the display names. When you **set** that property, OOM parses the value into multiple strings and calls IMessage::ModifyRecipients once for all specified recipients. When you call MailItem.Recipients.Add, IMessage::ModifyRecipients is called for each recipient, which is not very efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that up! The addresses I will be writing to `To`, `CC` and `BCC` all originate from the `AddressEntry.Address` field (but they do a roundtrip to a web service first, and the address list I get back may differ slightly). Is it safe to assume that `AddressEntry.Address` never contains a semicolon?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you actually get an SMTP address (AddressEntry.Type == "SMTP"). If you have "EX", use AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PriimarySmtpAddress and be prepared to handle errors.

Comment: Thus far I haven't had any problems with Exchange addresses at all. Maybe I've simply been lucky?

Comment: To clarify, I have yet to see an Exchange address that breaks when written to the `To` property.

Comment: If you are processing the addresses externally, EX type addresses will not make any sense outside of the EX domain.

Comment: All external processing is done on the SMTP addresses. The Exchange addresses are kept around in order to be able to reconstruct the recipient list as it was originally.