# Outlook VSTO Add-in: Removing a lot of recipients is too slow and not always work

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I have an VSTO Outlook Add-in. In the compose windows I have a button. When this button is clicked the recipients that satisfy a condition are removed. The recipients that need to be deleted are stored in a list, that is, List<Outlook.Recipient>. I iterate this list and remove each recipient.

```
foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in this.RecipientsList)
{
    this.MyMailItem?.Recipients?.Remove(recipient.Index);
}

// clear all the recipients
this.RecipientsList.Clear();
```

I have noted that the more recipients need to be removed the more slower is and also not always all the recipients contained in the list are removed, sometimes yet and sometimes not. Two things here:

- How can I optimize the speed for removing recipients?
- Why sometimes all the recipients contained in the list are not being removed? It's randomly, sometimes yes, sometimes not.

Note that this.MyMailItem is of type Outlook.MailItem and this.MyMailItem.Recipients is of type Outlook.Recipients.

Remove function requires an integer as a parameter, this is what its definition says, see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping Outlook COM objects in the collections is not really a good idea. Instead, you can keep their indexes and etc.

In the following loop:

```
foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in this.RecipientsList)
{
    this.MyMailItem?.Recipients?.Remove(recipient.Index);
}
```

The `recipient` object is ignored!

You could use the following:

```
foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in this.RecipientsList)
{
    recipient.Delete();
}
```

The [Recipient.Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.delete) method deletes an object from the collection.

The rule of thumb is to release underlying COM objects instantly. In that case you may be sure that objects are released timely. For example, in the code each time in the loop you get the Recipients collection which increases the reference counter:

```
this.MyMailItem?.Recipients
```

I'd recommend keeping the collection and only deal with a specific items in the loop:

```
Outlook.Recipients recipients = this.MyMailItem?.Recipients;
// in the loop you can call the Remove method
recipients.Remove(recipient.Index);
```

Also you may try to get a specific recipient instance in the loop and delete it. After that you also need to release an underlying COM object:

```
Outlook.Recipient recipient = null;
Outlook.Recipients recipients = this.MyMailItem?.Recipients;
for(int i = 1; i<recipients.Count;i++)
{
    recipient = this.RecipientsList.Item(i);
    recipient.Delete();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipient);
    recipient = null;
}
```

Comment: In your last piece of code you do recipient = this.RecipientsList[i] but this can raise and out of range exception since RecipientsList is always: RecipientsList.Count <= recipients. I mean, RecipientsLIst can contain the same number of recipients than recipients or less. I am trying to delete all the recipients from RecipientsList that are contained within this.MyMailItem.Recipients collection.

Comment: That was a raw sketch, I didn't check it out in the IDE. You can try using the Item method instead of indexer in C#.

Comment: Okay, thanks, and how can i release a list of recipients List<Outlook.Recipient> ? do i need to loop the entire list and for each item do a Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipient) and then set to null ?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on where you retrieved these instances.

Comment: And why there are sometimes that all the recipients are not being removed at once? i need to click on the button several times.

Comment: Do you release underlying COM objects? What is your current code?

Comment: The problem was keeping Outlook COM objects in the collections. This generates a lot of problems as Eugene said. I removed all them and changed them into a simple list of strings, display names and e-mail addresses. Also I optimize the way to remove to avoid flickering by doing something similar to what is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33871729/1624552

Answer (score 1):

Recipient count is changing dynamically inside for loop so not all recipients get cleared in for loop. i used below code as a workaround.

```
while (recipients.Count>0)
{
  recipients.Remove(recipients.Count);
}
```